# Get square brackets instead of "( )" brackets in the blkarray environment

Tags: arrays

How to get square brackets in this matrix instead of the "()" brackets:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
a & b & c & d & e \\
\begin{block}{(ccccc)c}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & f \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & g \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & h \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & i \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & j \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
 \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well… write square brackets instead of parentheses: `{[ccccc]c}`.

Comment: @Bernard Can you write an answer to get the question off the unanswered question list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `{[cccc]c}` instead of `{(cccc)c}` . Another point is that the size of the brackets produced by `blkarray` are often very short. You can improve it  using `bigstrut`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
a & b & c & d & e \\
\begin{block}{[ccccc]c}
\bigstrut[t] 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & f \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & g \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & h \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & i \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & j\bigstrut[b]\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]