# creating a matrix with rows and columns numbered on outside

Tags: math-mode

```
$$
\text{i: current-state}\Bigg\{\begin{matrix}0 \\  1 \\ 2\end{matrix}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}P_{00} & P_{01} & P_{02} \\ P_{10} & P_{11} & P_{12} \\ P_{20} & P_{21} & P_{22}\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{j: next-state: 0, 1 ,2 }}
$$
```

What's the best way to create a matrix with rows and columns numbered...

Comment: The code throws errors (`\Bigg{` should probably be `\Biggl\{`) and there is only one row in this matrix. Please try to explain the problem better.

Comment: Off-topic: in LaTeX don't use `$$`. Rather use `\[` ... `\]`.

Comment: The best way is use of the tools with which you are familiar. For example see `nicetabular`  (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512393/labeling-the-rows-of-a-matrix-with-letters or answer below) or `blkarray` (see example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335444/get-square-brackets-instead-of-brackets-in-the-blkarray-environment).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a suggestion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\begin{document}


$\begin{array}{c@{}c}
\text{text} \left\{\begin{array}{c@{}}
0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\
\end{array}\right.
& \left[\begin{array}{@{}*{3}{wc{5mm}}@{}}
$P_{00}$ & $P_{01}$ & $P_{02}$ \\
$P_{10}$ & $P_{11}$ & $P_{12}$ \\
$P_{20}$ & $P_{21}$ & $P_{22}$ \\
\end{array}\right]\\
&
\underbrace{\begin{array}{@{}*{3}{wc{5mm}}@{}}
0 & 1 & 2 
\end{array}}_{\text{text}}
 \end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Remark: In the future version of LaTeX (oct. 2020), the `wc` columns of `array` will be in math mode whereas they are in text mode as of now.